# Spring Boot custom validator doesn't return to Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am developing basic reset password flow. This is my DTO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@FieldsValueMatch(field = "password", fieldMatch = "confirmPassword", message = "Passwords do not match")
public class PasswordResetForm {
    @Size(min = 8, message = "Password needs to have at least 8 characters")
    private String password;
    private String confirmPassword;
}
```

There is `FieldsValueMatch` annotation:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = FieldsValueMatchValidator.class)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface FieldsValueMatch {
    String message() default "Fields values don't match!";

    String field();

    String fieldMatch();

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And validator:

```
public class FieldsValueMatchValidator implements ConstraintValidator<FieldsValueMatch, Object> {

    private String field;
    private String fieldMatch;

    @Override
    public void initialize(FieldsValueMatch constraintAnnotation) {
        this.field = constraintAnnotation.field();
        this.fieldMatch = constraintAnnotation.fieldMatch();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        Object fieldValue = new BeanWrapperImpl(value).getPropertyValue(field);
        Object fieldMatchValue = new BeanWrapperImpl(value).getPropertyValue(fieldMatch);

        if (fieldValue != null) {
            return fieldValue.equals(fieldMatchValue);
        } else {
            return fieldMatchValue == null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class ResetPasswordController {

    @ModelAttribute("passwordResetForm")
    public PasswordResetForm passwordResetForm() {
        return new PasswordResetForm();
    }

    @GetMapping("/reset-password")
    public String showResetPasswordForm(final Model model) {
        return "reset-password";
    }

    @PostMapping("/reset-password-result")
    public String resetPassword(@Valid final PasswordResetForm passwordResetForm,
                                final BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "reset-password";
    }
        // reset password logic
        return "redirect:/reset-password-success";
    }
}
```

and part of Thymeleaf page:

```
<form th:action="@{/reset-password-result}" th:object="${passwordResetForm}" method="post">
    <div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="password"
                   class="form-input"
                   placeholder="Set a new password"
                   type="password"
                   th:field="*{password}"/>
        </div>
        <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="confirmPassword"
                   class="form-input"
                   placeholder="Re-type a new password"
                   type="password"
                   th:field="*{confirmPassword}"/>
        </div>
        <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('confirmPassword')}" th:errors="*{confirmPassword}"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="form-btn">SET</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And now, when I enter different passwords in both inputs, I get the following message in terminal:

```
2021-03-26 11:13:39.315  WARN 1340 [nio-8080-exec-7] 
s.w.s.h.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved 
[org.springframework.validation.BindException: 
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Error in object 'passwordResetForm': codes 
[FieldsValueMatch.passwordResetForm,FieldsValueMatch]; arguments 
[org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [passwordResetForm.,]; arguments []; default message [],password,confirmPassword]; default message [Passwords do not match]]
```

and instant 400 result code. My `resetPassword` method in the Controller is not called, so instead my Thymeleaf page I get Whitelabel Error Page. The same happens when I put password shorter than 8 characters. What am I doing wrong?

I'd appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you tried *not* putting valid on `PasswordResetForm`?

Comment: yes, validation just doesn't work in that case

Comment: Has validation worked for you elsewhere? Perhaps you're facing [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66852380/input-validation-does-not-show-validation-error-java-spring)?

Comment: FWIW, your code seems to work when pasted in a brand new Spring Boot 2.4.4 project.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

thanks for all the replies. For no reason, it just started to work without any change from my side... I don't know what happened, maybe I needed to restart my web browser or something like this...

Answer (score 1):

You define `@FieldsValueMatch` as a class-level constraint. Probably the generated default constraint violation is causing the problem, since in this case no explicit property path is specified for the created constraint violation.

> The same happens when I put password shorter than 8 characters.

Regardless of the other field-level validation (= `@Size`), the `@FieldsValueMatch` will be executed in any case, which is probably why you are still facing the same problem.

So, adjusting the `FieldsValueMatchValidator` implementation - by setting the property path for the created constraint violation and providing a custom error message - should fix the problem:

```java
public class FieldsValueMatchValidator implements 
    ConstraintValidator<FieldsValueMatch, Object> {
    // ...
    private String message;

    @Override
    public void initialize(FieldsValueMatch constraintAnnotation) {
        // ...
        this.message = constraintAnnotation.message();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        //...
        boolean valid;

        if (fieldValue != null) {
            valid = fieldValue.equals(fieldMatchValue);
        } else {
            valid = fieldMatchValue == null;
        }

        if (!valid){
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(this.message) // setting the custom message
                    .addPropertyNode(this.field) // setting property path
                    .addConstraintViolation() // creating the new constraint violation 
                    .disableDefaultConstraintViolation() // disabling the default constraint violation
                    ;
        }

        return valid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `@Validated` annotation on `ResetPasswordController` class (before/after `@Controller` annotation). This should enabled validation

Comment: Valid should work as well, this is not a solution

Answer (score -1):

Check your method arguments sequence.

> **[Method Arguments](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.5/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments)**
>
> You must declare an `Errors`, or `BindingResult` argument immediately after the validated method argument.

So, if your code actually looks like following, your problem will be reproduced.

```java
    @PostMapping("/reset-password-result")
    public String resetPassword(@Valid PasswordResetForm passwordResetForm, Model model,
        BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "reset-password";
        }
        // reset password logic
        return "redirect:/reset-password-success";
    }
```

Comment: what is the difference compared to my code? Only model argument which is totally not needed here