# Input validation does not show validation error Java Spring

Tags: java, spring

model.User

```java
public class User {
    @NotEmpty(message="Field is empty")
    protected String FullName;
    ......
```

Main Controller
controllers.MainController

```java
@PostMapping("/registration")
public String submitForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("student") Student student, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    System.out.println(student.toString());
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    } else {
        return "registration_success";
    }
}
```

And my registration

```
<form class="registration_fields" action="#" th:action="@{/registration}" th:object="${student}" method="POST">
<label>Full Name:</label><input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{FullName}"><span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('FullName')}" th:errors="*{FullName}">Error</span><br>
.............
```

When I submit the form, nothing happens, the error isnt taken into account, and the message about it is not displayed

Console Output

```
Student{faculty='', cathedra='', group='', FullName='', birthday=null, end=2021-03-29, year=0}
```

Comment: Do you have a validator implementation in your classpath or only the API? ALso make sure you are using `javax.validation` not `jakarta.validation`.

Comment: @M.Deinum  Yeah, javax.validation. And I have only API..... Should I add dependecy in pom.xml?

Comment: Well. I Did it. Nothing happens.

Comment: @MadMoon you have to handle the exception, https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation follow the sample code

Comment: Make sure you are using the right versi9n. hibernate validator 7 or up won’t work you need 6 as that is voor javax.validation.

Comment: Yeah. I fixed. Thank you all!